# joomla 2.5 article urls are redirecting to homepage

Tags: php, joomla2.5

All article items are redirecting to homepage when I am using joomla 2.5 version given below is the anchor tag and on submit of image it should go to "coupons.html" but it is redirecting to homepage.

```
<a rel="allow" href="coupons.html"><img src="/images/sched-button.png" border="0" class="right" /></a>
```

Comment: Can you link to the website please, or give us more code, as that tiny bit of code tells us nothing...